# AWS CodeBuild Error, unsupported runtime version PHP 8.0

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am working with AWS CodeBuild, I am facing this issue where I am building a docker image for deployment. However, I am facing this issue where AWS shows me the error message of
`Unknown runtime version named '8.0' of php. This build image has the following versions: 7.3, 7.4`
However, in the [documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/codebuild/latest/userguide/available-runtimes.html) it says that it supports PHP V 8.0.
**Note that I am working with Laravel 9.0 with Laravel Sail, MySQL, Redis and MailHog containers.**

I am attaching my `buildspec.yml` file for reference

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions: 
      php: 8.0
    commands:
      - echo "PHP Version ⬇"
      - php -v
      - echo "Initiation of build "
      - echo "Installing Composer "
      - curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
      - mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
      - echo "Installing dependencies "
      - composer install
      - echo "Installed dependencies "

  build:
    commands:
      - echo "Building "
      - composer build
      - echo "Built "

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Post build "
      - echo "Build completed on `date` "
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Php  8.0 is [only supported](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/codebuild/latest/userguide/available-runtimes.html) if you use **Ubuntu standard:5.0** CodeBuild image. The fact that you are getting your error, means that you use different image then `Ubuntu standard:5.0`.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. Thanks for the info